# Add new items to JSON array after dynamic lookup

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component, dataweave, anypoint-studio

My sample payload is given below.

```
{
  "Identifier": "1111111111",
  "Type": "Test",
  "Codes": [
    {
      "CodeId": "112233-ABC",
      "Code": {
        "ID": "112233",
        "Name": "ABC"
      }
    },
    {
      "CodeId": "445566-DEF",
      "Code": {
        "ID": "445566",
        "Name": "DEF"
      }
    },
    {
      "CodeId": "778899-GHI",
      "Code": {
        "ID": "778899",
        "Name": "GHI"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I have 2 session variables as well given below:

```
%var var1 = 
{
  "112233": "900123",
  "445566": "900456",
  "778899": "900789"
}

%var var2 = 
{
  "value": [
    {
      "Desc": "Alpha",
      "TempId": 900123
    },
    {
      "Desc": "Bravo",
      "TempId": 900456
    },
    {
      "Desc": "Charlie",
      "TempId": 900789
    }
  ]
}
```

What I need is to do a dynamic lookup against these 2 variables and add new attribute(s) to the main payload, as given below:

```
{
  "Identifier": "1111111111",
  "Type": "Test",
  "Codes": [
    {
      "CodeId": "112233-ABC",
      "Code": {
        "ID": "112233",
        "Name": "ABC",
        "Description": "Alpha"
      }
    },
    {
      "CodeId": "445566-DEF",
      "Code": {
        "ID": "445566",
        "Name": "DEF",
        "Description": "Bravo"
      }
    },
    {
      "CodeId": "778899-GHI",
      "Code": {
        "ID": "778899",
        "Name": "GHI",
        "Description": "Charlie"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The idea is to perform lookup using **value** from var1 against **TempId** in var2 and get **Desc**. This has to be added to the Code array by matching with ID. If no value found, then insert null. **I am on dataweave 1.0**

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try the below script. There are two lookups, first is from `var` to get the `TempId` and then second is to add `Desc` field

```
%dw 1.0
%input payload application/json
%output application/json
%var var1 = 
{
  "112233": "900123",
  "445566": "900456",
  "778899": "900789"
}
%var var2 = 
{
  "value": [
    {
      "Desc": "Alpha",
      "TempId": 900123
    },
    {
      "Desc": "Bravo",
      "TempId": 900456
    },
    {
      "Desc": "Charlie",
      "TempId": 900789
    }
  ]
}
%var var2Grouped = var2.value groupBy $.TempId
%function addDesc(id) var2Grouped[var1[id]][0].Desc  default {}
---
{
  Identifier: payload.'Identifier',
  'Type': payload.'Type',
  "Codes": payload."Codes" map ((code) -> {
    CodeId: code.CodeId,
    Code: code.Code ++ addDesc(code.Code.ID)
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't have ability to test this with `DW 1.0` but you can try this function. It will only get the first match but also sets the description to `null` if no match is found. *(You could also use the `filter` function here instead of `[?(...)]`)*

```
%function getDescription(code) { 
    Description: var2.value[?(var1[code] ~= $.TempId)][0].Desc default null
}
```

And then this would be the expression to set the result payload

```
{
    Identifier: payload.Identifier,
    Type: payload.Type,
    Codes: payload.Codes map {
        ($ mapObject {
            (($$): $ ++ getDescription($.ID)) if(($$ as :string) == "Code"),
            (($$): $) if (($$ as :string) != "Code")
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I get some syntax errors with this, probably due to %dw 1.0